# Button click not selecting desired jquery tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I click btnSelect nothing happens. I want it to select the second of 2 tabs, the second tab having an index of 1. I deleted some extraneous markdown

Here is my code

```
 <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#tabs-left").tabs();
          $("#tabs-right").tabs();
          $("btnSelect").click(function () {
              $("#tabs-left").tabs("option", "active", 1);
          });

      });







  </script>

      <div id="tabs-left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Select Template</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Edit Template</a></li>
        </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
         <p>jQuery dropdown here</p>
         <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" />
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
         <p>jQuery rich text box here</p>

             <asp:Button id="btnReset" runat="server"  Text="Reset" /> 
             <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAs" runat="server" Text="Save As" /></div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to `$("#<%=btnSelect.ClientID %>")` instead of  `$("btnSelect")`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't select button properly.

You need to get the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET by using [`ClientID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.8) as following.

```
 $("#<%=btnSelect.ClientID %>").click(function () {
              $("#tabs-left").tabs("option", "active", 1);
          });
```

Also second issue here you should add `OnClientClick="return false;"` to active tab on index 1:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
```

Comment: After making change recommended by Selim the focus shifts to the desired tab but snaps back to tab 0 right away. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Just add to  `OnClientClick="return false;"` to button like `<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClientClick="return false;"/>`.